# How to efficiently divide file columns by one another using bash?

Tags: awk

I have a large text file with the format:

```
cat 10 5 20
pig 20 5 25
dog 0 5 0
goat 10 0 10
sheep 0 0 0
```

How can I use awk to add two new columns, one containing column 2 divided by column 4, and one containing column 3 divided by column 4? If the denominator is 0 then I would like to insert a 0. For example:

```
cat 10 5 20 0.5 0.25 
pig 20 5 25 0.8 0.2
dog 0 5 0 0 0 0
goat 10 0 10 1 0 
sheep 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried:

```
awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $2/$4, $3/$4 }' input_file > output_file
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
fatal: division by zero attempted
```

The file is very large so performance is important. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since performance is important testing $4 once would be faster than testing it twice:

```
awk '$4{print $0, $2/$4, $3/$4; next} {print $0, 0, 0}' Input_file
```

The tradeoff for the improved performance is the duplicate code (2 `print $0`s) but that's obviously minimal in this case and all solutions have some code duplication.

I was curious and decided to time all 3 current answers (mine, [@Ravinders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500088/1745001) and [@Inians](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61499896/1745001)). Here's the 3rd-run timing results using GNU awk on MacOS with a 10 million line file generated by running `awk '{for (i=1; i<=2000000; i++) print}' file > file10m` on the OPs provided sample input.

```
$ time awk '$4{print $0, $2/$4, $3/$4; next} {print $0, 0, 0}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m10.087s
user    0m10.009s
sys     0m0.054s

$ time awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 : 0), ($4 ? $3/$4 : 0)}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m10.329s
user    0m10.249s
sys     0m0.060s

$ time awk '{ $(NF+1) = ($4 ? $2/$4 :0); $(NF+1) = ($4 ? $3/$4 :0)  }1' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m11.293s
user    0m11.208s
sys     0m0.063s
```

and using the default OSX awk there:

```
$ time /usr/bin/awk '$4{print $0, $2/$4, $3/$4; next} {print $0, 0, 0}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m13.383s
user    0m13.240s
sys     0m0.123s

$ time /usr/bin/awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 : 0), ($4 ? $3/$4 : 0)}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m14.293s
user    0m14.082s
sys     0m0.161s

$ time /usr/bin/awk '{ $(NF+1) = ($4 ? $2/$4 :0); $(NF+1) = ($4 ? $3/$4 :0)  }1' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m15.668s
user    0m15.516s
sys     0m0.130s
```

so Inians approach in those tests was about 12-17% slower than mine and Ravinders about 2-7% slower with different speed improvements depending on awk version.

I also tested `awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 OFS $3/$4 : 0 OFS 0)}'` but found that to be slightly slower than my above suggestion in GNU awk and slower still in OSX awk (similar timing to Ravinders), probably due to the string concatenations. Using a hard-coded `"0 0"` for the else part of the ternary to avoid concatenation in that leg produced a slight improvement in execution speed. With gawk:

```
$ time awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 OFS $3/$4 : "0 0")}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m10.145s
user    0m10.058s
sys     0m0.064s
```

and with BSD awk:

```
$ time /usr/bin/awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 OFS $3/$4 : "0 0")}' file10m >/dev/null

real    0m13.993s
user    0m13.818s
sys     0m0.139s
```

but it's still not quite as fast as my original suggestion above and I'm not convinced having to hard-code that string including what you hope the value of OFS will be is a worthwhile tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print $0, ($4 ? $2/$4 : 0), ($4 ? $3/$4 : 0)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation of above:*** Printing current line then checking condition if 4th field is NOT zero then print `$2/$4` or print `0`. Then again check 4th field is NOT zero then print `$3/$4` or print `0`.